# emgucv performance issue with video playback

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am coding on WPF+EmguCV 3.1.0, and I am hitting some performance issue on video playback.
The input stream resolution is 1920*1800. I use EmguCV's ImageBox in order to render each frame. UI update is performed within a DispatcherTimer, which ticks every 1 ms.

No support of CUDA. OpenCL + OpenCL GPU working.

The result is an unbearable slowness in displaying each frame. It simply takes too long. The video is not a video. It's like watching a frame every 10 seconds or so.

Any idea of what could be the reason?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried running an ImageBox in a WindowsFormsHost in WPF at any speed. The ImageBox is quite comfortable at 30fps @ 1080p in a simple WinForm app I wrote.

I have a WPF application that can run comfortably at 60fps @ 1080p, but I am not using an ImageBox or a WindowsFormsHost object!!!!! I use a Canvas and create a BitmapSource object from my frame and assign that to the Canvas background.

Unless I read your question wrong you are trying to refresh every 1ms, that's 1000fps and there is no possible way it will keep up with that. I know of no combination of processor and the highest power graphics card that can run at those frame rates in Windows! I am not sure even a 12Gb/s disk system will feed you that many fps.

Why not try slowing down to a normal speed and see if it works before slamming it.

Doug